Issue with Distributed Training Freezing During Initialization
I am experiencing an issue with my PyTorch distributed training setup where the process freezes during the initialization of the process group. Here are the details of my setup:
# Environment:
#    OS: [Your OS]
#    GPUs: 2x NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti
#    PyTorch Version: [Your PyTorch Version]
#    CUDA Version: [Your CUDA Version]
#    NCCL Version: [Your NCCL Version]
#    Backend: Tried with both nccl and gloo

# Script:

import os
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
from transformers import GPT2Config, GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, DistributedSampler
from tqdm import tqdm

def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'
    dist.init_process_group(backend="gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
    torch.cuda.set_device(rank)

def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()

class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, tokenizer, max_length=512):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            self.lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.lines)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        line = self.lines[idx]
        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            line,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )
        input_ids = encoding['input_ids'].squeeze(0)
        attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask'].squeeze(0)
        return input_ids, attention_mask

def train(rank, world_size):
    setup(rank, world_size)
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    config = GPT2Config.from_pretrained('gpt2')
    model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config).to(rank)
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])
    file_path = 'data/corpus_filtered.txt'
    dataset = TextDataset(file_path, tokenizer)
    sampler = DistributedSampler(dataset, num_replicas=world_size, rank=rank)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, sampler=sampler)
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
    model.train()
    checkpoint_dir = 'checkpoints'
    if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
        os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'checkpoint.pth')
    start_epoch = 0
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_path):
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location='cpu')
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
        start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch'] + 1

    epochs = 3
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, epochs):
        epoch_iterator = tqdm(dataloader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs} (Rank {rank})", unit="batch")
        for batch in epoch_iterator:
            input_ids, attention_mask = [x.to(rank) for x in batch]
            outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=input_ids)
            loss = outputs.loss.mean()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            epoch_iterator.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())
        if rank == 0:
            checkpoint = {
                'epoch': epoch,
                'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            }
            torch.save(checkpoint, checkpoint_path)
    cleanup()
    if rank == 0:
        model.module.save_pretrained('gpt2-custom')
        tokenizer.save_pretrained('gpt2-custom')

def main():
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'
    mp.spawn(train, args=(world_size,), nprocs=world_size, join=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Problem: The script freezes during the initialization of the process group. Both ranks print "Initializing process group...", but it does not proceed beyond this point.

Steps Taken:
Tried both nccl and gloo backends.
Verified that the MASTER_PORT is not being used by another process.
Ensured that there are no firewall or network issues.
Monitored GPU usage using nvidia-smi, and both GPUs are detected.
I expected that:

The script should initialize the process group for both ranks (0 and 1).
The training loop should start, with both GPUs being utilized for the training process.
Both ranks should proceed with the training, and the loss should be updated and printed.
The script should complete the training epochs and save checkpoints.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
